# Python: Plotting blocks on a polar grid (Basemap.pcolormesh)

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

I want to plot blocks of color on a polar grid. Currently (as seen below) the blocks do not follow the specified meridians and parallels.  I would like these blocks to fit within the arched boxes I have drawn.  Any help would be grately appreciated.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

fig = plt.figure()

cols = np.linspace(60,200,4)
rows = np.linspace(60,78,4)

ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
Z  = np.random.random( (4,4) )

m = Basemap(width=6500000, height=3000000,
        resolution='l', projection='stere',\
        lat_0=72, lon_0=130.)

### draw parallels and meridians.
m.drawparallels(rows, linewidth=0.7)
m.drawmeridians(cols, linewidth=0.7)
m.drawmapboundary()

x, y = m(*np.meshgrid(cols,rows))
m.pcolormesh(x, y, Z, vmin=0, vmax=1)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('sof_example.png')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no easy way to do it. The way I see it, python does not "know" about the map projection. What you plot is not lon/lat, but rather lon/lat that has been converted to axes coordinates by basemap. 
So what you can do is to do exactly what you've done but refine the plot grid.

This seems to do the trick, but it is a kind of "brute" solution ;-)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

fig = plt.figure()

cols = np.linspace(60,200,4)
rows = np.linspace(60,78,4)

ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
Z  = np.random.random( (4,4) )

m = Basemap(width=6500000, height=3000000,
        resolution='l', projection='stere',\
        lat_0=72, lon_0=130.,ax=ax)

### draw parallels and meridians.
m.drawparallels(rows, linewidth=0.7)
m.drawmeridians(cols, linewidth=0.7)
m.drawmapboundary()

### set up new cols, rows and z that are on high-res grid
cols2 = np.linspace(cols[0],cols[-1],100)
rows2 = np.linspace(rows[0],rows[-1],100)
Z2    = np.zeros((100,100))

for i in range(0,cols.shape[0]-1):
   for j in range(0,rows.shape[0]-1):
      ### find corresponding cols, rows on high-res grid
      i0 = np.where(np.abs(cols2-cols[i]) == np.min(np.abs(cols2-cols[i])))[0]
      i1 = np.where(np.abs(cols2-cols[i+1]) == np.min(np.abs(cols2-cols[i+1])))[0]
      j0 = np.where(np.abs(rows2-rows[j]) == np.min(np.abs(rows2-rows[j])))[0]
      j1 = np.where(np.abs(rows2-rows[j+1]) == np.min(np.abs(rows2-rows[j+1])))[0]
      ### put Z value in new Z2 array 
      Z2[j0:j1+1,i0:i1+1] = Z[j,i]

x,y = m(*np.meshgrid(cols2,rows2))
m.pcolormesh(x,y,Z2,vmin=0,vmax=1)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('sof_example.png')

plt.show()
```